# Adobe Photoshop UXP: How to call "Fit to Screen" in UXP JavaScript?

Tags: plugins, scripting, adobe, photoshop

I'm converting working CEP/ExtendScript to UXP JavaScript.

Is there any way to use Zoom Fit to Screen (same as Ctrl+0) in UXP scripting?

In CEP/ExtendScript, we can use as following.

```
app.runMenuItem(app.charIDToTypeID("FtOn"));
// Fit to Screen (same as Ctrl+0)
```

It seems not implemented simiar way on Photoshop UXP DOM as

```
require('photoshop').app.runMenuItem(1182027630);
```

Result:

[image]

From UXP Alchemist plugin's Listner is showing:

```
{
  "_obj": "invokeCommand",
  "commandID": 1192,
  "kcanDispatchWhileModal": true,
  "_isCommand": false
}
```

From batchPlay(), above seems not runnable (this part is not quite sure).

```
var result = require('photoshop').action.batchPlay([
    {
        "_obj": "invokeCommand",
        "commandID": 1192,
        "kcanDispatchWhileModal": true,
        "_isCommand": false
    }
], {synchronousExecution: true});
```

Result:

[image]

I'm not quite sure if above is proper usage of batchPlay() as well.

But is there any way to use Zoom Fit to Screen (same as Ctrl+0) in UXP scripting?

Comment: `invokeCommand` is a garbage helper-action that often appears in listeners but you can't run it. I'd try to put the menu item in an action, convert it to a script and then convert the resulting AM script to UXP batchplay

Comment: I have the Action Descriptor converter (ad-to-uxp.jsx) and use other task conversion. It worked well. But I could not find any way still for ExtendScript's app.runMenuItem().

Comment: A lot of things from ES don’t exist in UXP. This is our life now

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
const {executeAsModal} = require("photoshop").core;
const {batchPlay} = require("photoshop").action;

async function actionCommands() {
   const result = await batchPlay(
      [
         {
            _obj: "select",
            _target: [
               {
                  _ref: "menuItemClass",
                  _enum: "menuItemType",
                  _value: "fitOnScreen"
               }
            ],
            _options: {
               dialogOptions: "dontDisplay"
            }
         }
      ],
      {}
   );
}

async function runModalFunction() {
   await executeAsModal(actionCommands, {"commandName": "Action Commands"});
}

await runModalFunction();
```